# /dev/hidraw: read permissions

Tags: devices, udev

What do I need to do to have read permissions on /dev/hidraw*?

I'm seeing stuff about udev rules and saw [this](https://github.com/ways/coffeeleft/blob/master/etc/udev/rules.d/99-hidraw-permissions.rules) on the net, but the world of udev is like a foreign land to me, and if there's some sort of a simpler solution where I just add myself to a group that'd be dandy...

(Ubuntu 13.10 Preview)

Feel free to retag the question - I'm not too keen on what 'hidraw' exactly goes under.

EDIT:

H'okay, so, just some more information to clarify the issue:
I literally stepped through code that called the POSIX `open()` method, and got the `errno` for insufficient permissions. Running `cat` on the file as a normal user results in an insufficient permissions error, while running under `su` results in a successful (albeit meaningless) `cat` operation.

EDIT EDIT:

At request, I'm providing the relevant code with POSIX call. It's from the HIDAPI library by Signal11 (function `hid_open_path`). I trust that this code is correct, as it has apparently been in use for quite some time now. I've added a comment located where the relevant `errno` reading took place in GDB.

```
hid_device *dev = NULL;

hid_init();

dev = new_hid_device();

if (kernel_version == 0) {
    struct utsname name;
    int major, minor, release;
    int ret;
    uname(&name);
    ret = sscanf(name.release, "%d.%d.%d", &major, &minor, &release);
    if (ret == 3) {
        kernel_version = major << 16 | minor << 8 | release;
        //printf("Kernel Version: %d\n", kernel_version);
    }
    else {
        printf("Couldn't sscanf() version string %s\n", name.release);
    }
}

/* OPEN HERE */
dev->device_handle = open(path, O_RDWR);

// errno at this location is 13: insufficient permissions

/* If we have a good handle, return it. */
if (dev->device_handle > 0) {

    /* Get the report descriptor */
    int res, desc_size = 0;
    struct hidraw_report_descriptor rpt_desc;

    memset(&rpt_desc, 0x0, sizeof(rpt_desc));

    /* Get Report Descriptor Size */
    res = ioctl(dev->device_handle, HIDIOCGRDESCSIZE, &desc_size);
    if (res < 0)
        perror("HIDIOCGRDESCSIZE");


    /* Get Report Descriptor */
    rpt_desc.size = desc_size;
    res = ioctl(dev->device_handle, HIDIOCGRDESC, &rpt_desc);
    if (res < 0) {
        perror("HIDIOCGRDESC");
    } else {
        /* Determine if this device uses numbered reports. */
        dev->uses_numbered_reports =
            uses_numbered_reports(rpt_desc.value,
                                  rpt_desc.size);
    }

    return dev;
}
else {
    /* Unable to open any devices. */
    free(dev);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: @Braiam Code snippet added.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I gave up running around trying to figure out some other means of doing it than udev rules, and instead just learned a bit about udev and wrote a flippin' rule. The following line was placed in a `.rules` file (I named mine `99-hidraw-permissions.rules`) located under `/etc/udev/rules.d`.

```
KERNEL=="hidraw*", SUBSYSTEM=="hidraw", MODE="0660", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Basically this assigns all devices coming out of the hidraw subsystem in the kernel to the group `plugdev` and sets the permissions to r/w r/w r (for root [the default owner], plugdev, and everyone else respectively). With myself added to the plugdev group, everything's dandy.

Not quite as brain melting as I'd expected. Udev rules actually seem pretty straightforward... I mean, they look like they *can* get ridiculous if you're dealing with individual product IDs and whatnot, but they seem pretty damn tame for what they do.

Comment: This worked for me as i wanted to use Roccat configuration tool, and it needed root permissions. With this i can use the tool with normal user.

Comment: I had a ledger device plugged into my Raspberry Pi 3b+ - Node HID was trying to gain access to it and was failing. Adding this file with the line you listed worked like a charm, just needed to unplug and plug the device in after adding the file.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 20.04. This worked. I wonder how safe this is?

Answer (score 10):

> To understand something... start being knowing of it.

Ok, first of all, lets see what `hidraw` means and what is composed of:

- hid (Human Interface Device): A human interface device or HID is a type of computer device that interacts directly with, and most often takes input from, humans and may deliver output to humans. <sub>[source wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_interface_device)</sub>
- raw: This is meant as *crude*, but in the Linux ambiance it also means direct.

From this we can infer that `hidraw` is a *crude/direct* method to access the *hid*. Now lets look what our systems think about this:

```
$ ls -l /dev/hidraw*
crw------- 1 root root 251, 0 Aug  3  2013 /dev/hidraw0
crw------- 1 root root 251, 1 Aug  3  2013 /dev/hidraw1
crw------- 1 root root 251, 2 Aug  3  2013 /dev/hidraw2
$ file /dev/hidraw*
/dev/hidraw0: character special 
/dev/hidraw1: character special 
/dev/hidraw2: character special
```

So, what `character special` means? Character special files or character devices relate to devices through which the system transmits data one character at a time by, for example, `getchar`. <sub>[again Wikipedia is our friend](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Character_devices)</sub> The same follows the `c` at the start of the `ls -l` command.

> What do I need to do to have read permissions on /dev/hidraw*?

So, how this solve your question? For accessing the `/dev/hidraw*` you should use the C implementation to read/write to this file. But, if what you want is information about the HID's connected you should look in `/sys/class/hidraw/hidraw*/`. Example:

```
$ cat /sys/class/hidraw/hidraw2/device/uevent
DRIVER=hid-generic
HID_ID=0003:000015D9:00000A4C
HID_NAME= USB OPTICAL MOUSE
HID_PHYS=usb-0000:00:1d.1-2/input0
HID_UNIQ=
MODALIAS=hid:b0003g0001v000015D9p00000A4C
```

Take into account that only the kernel has direct access in most of the cases to the devices, and you should only use the calls provided in userspace to communicate with these devices.

> I'm seeing stuff about udev rules and saw this on the net, but the world of udev is like a foreign land to me

Unless you are developing a new driver/device you shouldn't play too much around `udev`, you can get your brain permanently damaged.

Comment: I literally stepped through code that called the POSIX `open()` method, and got the `errno` for insufficient permissions. Running `cat` on the file as a normal user results in an insufficient permissions error, while running under `su` results in a successful (albeit meaningless) `cat` operation. While I appreciate the extra info, it doesn't actually help with my lack of permissions problem... Also, I'm working with an experimental HID, so I'm totally okay with getting my brain full of hurts-so-good udev stuff it's necessary.